# Disable mouse speed check between monitors in windows 8.1 update 1

Tags: windows-8.1

In windows 8.1 and below, the mouse would seamlessly move through all my monitors.

However, in windows 8.1 update 1 the mouse needs to be going at a certain speed before it goes to a different monitor. How do I disable this?

A google search has turned up nothing, so I'm not sure what exactly is going on

Comment: @TorpedoBench what do you want me to say. I have researched it but nothing showed up. Windows 8.1 was released hours ago so there won't be anything that shows up soon. As long as it hasn't been asked on SU before it's encouraged to ask - google has to index something and it might as well be SO.

Comment: Things like links to other forums or discussion sites showing that others are experiencing the same event you are. Hours is enough time for things like this to start cropping up. Without knowing if other users are experiencing this, it could be something on your end.

Comment: @TorpedoBench Either way, it's encouraged to ask questions if it's not on SO it's encouraged to be ask. Furthermore, there's nothing that comes up so I *can't* link to anything. My brother is also experiencing it so I assume it's not specific to me.

Comment: That's not what I'm questioning. I'm citing the lack of research beyond Stack Exchange. Even a simple statement like "A google search has turned up nothing, so I'm not sure what exactly is going on" would make me retract my vote. That's why I said no /evident/ research effort.

Comment: @TorpedoBench I added to that the post. Either way, it's encouraged to ask questions on SO *even if it's answered elsewhere*.

Comment: The tooltip itself for the downvote button lists no research effort as a reason to downvote. You showed no effort to research the issue in your post, regardless of if you did or not, thus my voting and leaving the initial comment. If it's answered elsewhere, you should show that either in an edit to your question or in a comment.

Comment: @TorpedoBench I don't think you're reading my posts. **Even if it is answered elsewhere, it is fine to ask with no mention whatsoever**. The logic behind this is that google has to index *something*, and it might as well be SO. Mine hasn't been answered at all.

Comment: Upvote as I don't want to deal with this when I get home. ;)

Comment: Is it just me or did they apparently undo this feature in a recent update? My mouse was sticky up til early today, I did an "Update and restart" and messed with video driver stuff, and now it's not sticking. Presumably the windows update undid it..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Jason Stevenson's solution worked best for me, however I found a case when it does not work as expected.

This `MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed` value does not seem to be a True/False toggle with 0/1, but more an integer value. A value of 1 does not fix this issue in all scenarios moving from monitor to monitor.

To reproduce the issue when using 1 for `MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed`

1. Set both `MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed` registry entries to 1
2. Reboot the machine or restart the Explorer.exe process
3. Turn off taskbars on multiple displays (as shown by @vanquishuk)
4. Unlock the main taskbar and move it to the right side of the left monitor
5. Move the mouse very slowly from the left monitor to the right one (you should see the mouse get stuck for a little bit in between)
6. Moving from the right monitor to the left and the mouse does not stick

With the below registry entries I have found the solution works in all scenarios I can think of (including having the taskbar on the side of your monitor).

--- Registry File ---

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;
; Fix mouse stickiness between monitors and mouse getting stuck in corners between monitors
;

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"MouseCornerClipLength"="0"
"MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\EdgeUi]
"MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the .reg file :) Saves time navigating regedit.

Comment: Didn't work for me on Windows 10

Comment: There is a bug open for the MouseCornerClipLength setting which I also found does not work in windows 10. Microsoft has acknowledged it.

I have not attempted the MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed setting as it is not bothering me in windows 10. It seems to be disabled by default when you are not dragging a window. I will check if I can figure out how to turn it off though.

Comment: What values should I use if I want to *enable* this feature?? My windows 10 box lets the mouse go from one screen to the other without "catching" it for a while, which is a desired feature for me. I use one screen in top of the other, if that matters. This feature was in Windows 8.1 before I upgraded to Windows 10 a couple of days ago. I tried changing the three values to "1","10" and "100" to see if there's any difference, bot none had any effect. I am restarting explorer.exe between the tests.

Comment: I think this setting no longer works in windows 10, try looking in settings under System>Multitasking.

Comment: For Windows 10 you can try a small app that will hop out of stuck corners: http://www.jawfin.net/?page_id=143

Answer (score 17):

The selected answer no longer solves the issue on the most recent Windows 8.1 updates, or in Windows 10.

To properly solve this issue in later Windows versions you must edit this key here, changing the value from 0 to **1**:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed
```

And you must also add a missing key to the following location:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\EdgeUI
```

Create a DWORD value **MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed** set to **1**

Finally you must kill the **Explorer.exe** process from task manager, and then re-launch it; alternatively you could restart your PC for the change to take affect.

Comment: Not working for me in Windows 10

Comment: Still works for me on the release build... Did you remember to kill explorer or restart your PC?

Answer (score 5):

Found a way to fix it for my self. Un-check this box:
Right click task bar > Properties > Task bar Tab
Once un-checked hit apply, then you can re-check it and hit apply again and the mouse should no longer get stuck.

[image]

Comment: I need the taskbar on all my displays though

Comment: @Chipperyman - turning it off and on seems to disable it for that session. Though this is likely a bug, and may be fixed by MS at some stage.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thank you @vanquishuk!

Comment: This also worked perfectly for me. Just uncheck the box, click apply, re-check the box, click apply or OK and problem solved. Thank you!

Comment: Update: this only worked temporarily. Jason Stevenson's answer works, hopefully permanently! I am running Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 5):

While some reported that this problem disappeared after changing seemingly unrelated windows settings (such as the "Show taskbar on all displays"), none of this worked for me.

However, after changing the registry value

```
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed
```

from it's default value (0 on Win 8.1 Pro build 9600) to 1 and rebooting the "sticky edges bug/feature" seems to be gone.

There is also `MouseCornerClipLength` in the same location which might be of interest if you want to disable the sticky corners too (set it to 0 in that case).

**EDIT** 
After changing `MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed` back to 0 the problem appeared again after hibernation. Value 1 seems to disable sticky monitor edges without any side effects.

Comment: Re: Setting MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed to 1 - I've noticed that upon immediate boot up, the sticky edges may still be there. If you wait 1-2 minutes, it then stops.

Comment: @TorpedoBench No longer works with new Windows 8.1 updates and Windows 10. See my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10, go to:

`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center\Make the mouse easier to use`

which I found by searching settings for 'edge'.

Check the box for `Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen`.

Comment: While that solves the in-between monitors issues for dragging windows between displays, it also deactivates the feature for dragging a window towards the top of a screen to maximize it. It turns off the feature completely. I want to keep the Win7 portion, but disable the Win8/10 parts.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still has this issue in windows 10. Check in Settings->Display to make sure your screen arrangement is as tight as possible (smallest possible gaps). When there is a big gap, the mouse will require a proportional amount of additional pixel movement to reach the next screen (Moving the mouse faster based on the size of the gap).

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting. Otherwise, consider adding some reference to this answer supporting what you state.

Comment: I just figured out the same @Lance. Windows 10 user here. I have 6 monitors, 2 rows of 3, one on top of the other. One of the vertical pairs had this issue, the others did not. There was a small sliver of space between those two monitors in Display Settings (where you arrange the positioning of your monitors) but not the others. Removing that little space fixed it.

Comment: You can have gaps? I've never been allowed that. The monitors stick to eachother like magnets when I arrange them.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that does not need an explorer.exe restart or system reboot.

> Steps:
>
> 1. go to start screen
> 2. click a metro app (onenote in my test case)
> 3. move mouse to top left corner and click so it switches app (to desktop or to another metro app; doesn't matter)
>
> Now mouse will be sticky thru out ALL edges of the monitors.

It comes from user Riasat from MS forum: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-tms/mouse-stickiness-change-with-multiple-monitors/a4eb4cc9-def1-4e80-b823-83460339afb8

You can close the metro app after it or kill it through task manager.

Hope this will help you it's really annoying bug O.o