# Windows 8.1 multi monitor setup with a vertical taskbar grabs mouse when moving across border

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, mouse, taskbar

So I'm having a problem with what I believe to be a recent Windows 8.1 update (probably [KB2919355](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919355)). I use a vertical taskbar on the right side between two monitors. When I move my mouse across the split at a slow enough speed, the mouse ends up "sticking" to the current monitor. This catches me off guard several times a day at least and I find it intensely annoying. I haven't found any option to turn it off.

It also happens when the taskbar is on the left on the other monitor. It does not happen when there are no taskbars on that edge. It may also happen with a horizontal taskbar in a multimonitor layout with screens stacked vertically, but I haven't tested this.

[image: Visual reference]

Any ideas on how to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same issue as [Disable mouse speed check between monitors in windows 8.1 update 1](https://superuser.com/questions/739355/disable-mouse-speed-check-between-monitors-in-windows-8-1-update-1).

In my testing of this issue I found that changing the setting to 1 just decreases the speed at which the mouse sticks. Please see my solution in the other post for details.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to create a .reg file from Sergey Tkachenko's solution in Taudris answer, in case someone doesn't want to change the keys manually each time this issue comes up:

1. Save the following code in a new textdocument,
2. change its extension to .reg,
3. double click it to merge it into the registry.

Then just reboot to apply the changes.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\EdgeUi]
"MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Don’t you need to set `MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed` in `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop`? Your `.REG` file doesn’t appear to do so. Also, Sergey Tkachenko’s step #5 says that restarting Windows Explorer is all you need to do to get this to take effect. The simple way of doing this is to logout and login again, but he documents ways of doing it without logging out. Do you suggest rebooting for any particular reason?

Comment: @Scott: You're right, thanks for the comment. I've updated the code snippet accordingly. And there is no particular reason to explicitly suggest restarting, I was just harnessing the restart-to-apply-changes meme for conciseness.

Answer (score 1):

I tried searching some more today using "sticks", and found this:

> This sticking of the mouse cursor on the right edge of monitor 1 and
>   the left edge of monitor 2 (shared edge) is a feature to make the
>   charms bar and scroll bars easier to use. Luckily you can disable it.
>
> 1. Open Registry Editor (see how)
> 2. Go to the following key:
>
>    `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop`
> 3. Look for a `DWORD` value called `MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed`. If that value does not exist, then create it. Change its value data to 1.
>      [image: MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed]
> 4. Repeat steps #2 and #3 for the following Registry key too
>
>    `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\EdgeUI`
> 5. Now restart the Explorer.exe shell or restart Windows.

[Winaero.com: FIX: Mouse pointer sticks on the edge when moving between multiple monitors](http://winaero.com/blog/fix-mouse-pointer-sticks-on-the-edge-when-moving-between-multiple-monitors/)