# How to disable sticky corners in Windows 10?

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, windows-10-preview, cursor

My question is the same as this one : [How to disable sticky corners in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/498576/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-8)
But I didn't find the values to change in the registry.

Any idea how to fix this on Windows 10 ?

edit : I tried this : https://superuser.com/a/840335/465462 but it doesn't work.
I'm on build 10159.

Comment: update to 10162 and try again.

Comment: It doesn't work. I noticed the /EdgeUI/ key disapeared after I installed the 10162. I created it again, created the DWORD and set the value to 1, killed all the explorer.exe I could found, even restarted my computer… My mouse still hits the corner, that's incredibely annoying. Here is a screenshot of the value I created in the registry : http://i.imgur.com/kCvvHgU.png