# Dual monitors: how to enable cursor edge stickyness

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, mouse, regedit

I have recently put up my dual monitor setup, i was looking forward having the Sticky Cursor, but that feature didn't automatically turned on.

So i have been looking around, tried messing a little with **Regedit**, so i have set those following keys to **0** and vice versa to **1**.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\EdgeUI
```

Restarting Explorer.exe and even restarting the pc itself after every change wont apply my so desired stickiness.

how can i apply the following feature?

OS: Windows 8.1

Comment: I have used MultiMon Taskbar and has worked fantastic - http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm

Comment: @Leptonator i don't get it,,, how this suppose to help me?

Comment: I have used the application for years and you can run apps by monitor with it..  Love it!!

Comment: @Leptonator Multimon taskbar adds a taskbar to secondary monitors on Windows Vista / 7 - which is now provided by default on Win8+

Comment: you pretty much miss the point guys.. my problem is that my cursor is moving though screens with no speed limit, making it harder to get to specific buttons on the side of the screens. i pretty much want the old known Sticky cursor feature..

Comment: weird stuff, change the multimon WIN-P to one mon only, or clone, then back again, as that could change things. (because your retelling the software that it is 2 mon) .  Try playing with a metro app and see what happens.

Comment: @Psycogeek nothing seems to change.. may there is a global settings that i could reset or even replace some default registery files..? i don't know alot about it, maybe you do

Comment: What is the value of `MouseCornerClipLength` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` (should be 6)? Check also if the settings listed in [this article](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-hot-corners-charms-bar-and-app-switch-list-in-windows-8-1/) are enabled (doing the opposite of what the article says).

Comment: There's some interesting discussion about this in [this superuser post](http://superuser.com/questions/739355/disable-mouse-speed-check-between-monitors-in-windows-8-1-update-1), although it's actually about the opposite problem. It seems clear to me that the behaviour of the mouse pointer at monitor edges between screens is inconsistent, and may in fact depend on your display driver. On my Windows 8.1 dual monitor setup, the mouse only sticks between the monitors at the extreme top and bottom (i.e. the corners).

Comment: @boot13 well, i have already updated my graphic hardware drivers. both Intel and ATI.. it doesnt seems the problem

Comment: Unfortunately, updating your drivers doesn't magically fix all bugs. Just the ones the developers know about. And bothered to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 8.1  there is a 6 pixel area at the corners of the screen that will cause your cursor to stop so you can pull up the charms bars in a multi-monitor configuration. You can adjust the number of pixels in the registry:

```
HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\MouseCornerClipLength
```

It is also a speed issue. If you drag the mouse quickly, it won't stop at the edges, but move it slowly and it will stick.

I've found most users are trying to eliminate this feature, but the following articles give various ways to turn sticky features on and off:

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/49401-sticky-edges-multi-monitors-enable-disable.html

[How to disable sticky corners in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/498576/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-8)

http://winaero.com/blog/fix-mouse-pointer-sticks-on-the-edge-when-moving-between-multiple-monitors/

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/mouse-pointer-sticks-at-edge-windows

Comment: that did not solve my problem but it actually helped living with it. here, have my prize!

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/49396-sticky-corners-multi-monitors-enable-disable.html) that might help you with your issue. This is NOT sticky edges, but it should help you to use the Charms bar in a multiple monitor setup. The tutorial for sticky edges (which does not seem to be working for you anyways) is [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/49401-sticky-edges-multi-monitors-enable-disable.html).

1. Press the Windows Key + R keys to open the Run dialog, type regedit, and click/tap on OK.
2. If prompted by UAC, click/tap on Yes.
3. In Registry Editor, navigate to the location below. (see screenshot below)

   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop

[image]

4. In the right pane of the Desktop key, double click on the MouseCornerClipLength string value to modify it. (see screenshot above)
5. Type in a value between 0 to 20 for what you want, and click/tap on OK. (see screenshot below)

[image]